# Yii2 redirect 404 Page not found

Tags: view, controller, yii2-basic-app

I have custom page in view/stock/three.php ( which I make) , I render it in StockController , and I try to open it from  view/site/shop.php with

```
<div class="pager "><a href="<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/stock/three']) ?>">3</a></div>
```

but I get **Not Found (#404) Page not found.**  . ( I didnt forget to set "use Url")
I try also to redirect it from SiteController with :

```
public function actionThree() {
     return $this->redirect(['/stock/three']);
}
```

but also didnt work and still got **Error code 404**

Comment: What is your UrlManager configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make new Model  and new Controller for pages where I write :

```
public function actionThree() {
    return $this->render('three');
}
```

and then

```
<div class="pager "><a href="<?php echo Url::to(['pages/three']) ?>">3</a></div>
```

work

Answer (score 0):

maybe you don't have a 'three.php' file inside views/stock folder or that forward slash ('/') before 'stock'.

Comment: I make the ' three.php ' file  inside views/stock folder I try with and without the slash before 'stock' in both ways didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function actionThree() {
     return $this->redirect(['stock/three']);
}
```